# Solr combined (AND) query performance

Tags: performance, solr

Need to perform the following query in solr:

```
field_a:"A" AND field_b:/.*sear.* ph.ase.*/
```

- single `field_a:"A"` query is super fast;
- single `field_b:/.*sear.* ph.ase.*/` query is slowish;
- combined with `AND` query is slow too;

Setting either one of those query parts as filter doesn't work, the performance is still bad!

Is there a way to instruct solr to perform a search for the second query on the results of the first (to improve performance)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you make the first query a [filter query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#fq) instead of a regular query.  That tends to speed up the results in my experience.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, i have tried that too, same result, it is still slow, thanks!